# Checking for Prime Numbers

Tags: python, primes, python-2.x

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2:
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in xrange(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))
```

The code works fine for a range of numbers after that it shows:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

How can my code be made faster and more efficient?

Comment: Since the overflow happens only for very large _n_, I don't consider this to be broken code for the purpose of determining whether this question is on-topic.

Comment: @200_success how can i modify this to work for larger number.how to solve my purpose to find whaeter a long int is prime.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816603/range-is-too-large-python). I can't test this for you because I use Python 3.3, but this may solve your problem.

Comment: @DarinDouglass the code works but itertools examples doesn't have minimum range. i want to iterate from 3

Comment: If you look at the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for `itertools.count` you'll find it has a `start` (as well as a `step`) keyword parameter.

Comment: @DarinDouglass that solves the range problem. can u tell is there anything to make it more efficient.faster. iw as looking at the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin . which is said to be fastest way finding the primes

Comment: Well if that is the fastest algorithm for finding primes, that would definitely improve efficiency. You'll have to write that code yourself before we can code review it, though.

Comment: @DarinDouglass i am unable to understand the pseudocode there :( . how can v convert it to code any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

On a 64-bit CPython 2.x,

```
all(i for i in xrange(2**63 - 1))
```

works, but

```
all(i for i in xrange(2**63))
```

overflows.  See this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129017/1157100), and a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1482480/1157100).  I suggest rewriting this using an old-fashioned `while` loop.

With Python 3.x,

```
all(i for i in range(2**63))
```

works.

---

You've implemented trial division.  A more efficient algorithm is the [sieve-of-eratosthenes](/questions/tagged/sieve-of-eratosthenes), especially if you want to test multiple numbers for primality.  However, the Sieve of Eratosthenes requires more memory, so you'll have to resort to some hacks to make it work for large numbers.

For truly large numbers, you'll have to implement [more sophisticated algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).